# Using groupby() on an exploded pandas DataFrame returns a data frame where indeces are repeated but they have different attributes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-explode

I am working with a dataset found in kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/netflix-shows) which has data regarding different productions on Netflix. I am looking to answer the following question: How many productions are produced from each country.

Because there are productions which are essentially co-productions, meaning that under the column named 'country' there might be occasions where we have comma-separated strings in the form of : 'Country1','Country2',... etc, I have split the question into 2 parts:

The first part, is to filter the dataframe and keep only the rows which are single country productions and so we can find out how many productions are produced from each country provided that these are not co-productions. I encountered no problem during the first phase.

The second part is to take into account the co-productions. So, every time a country is found into a co-production the total number of it's productions is +=1.

The method I chose to solve the second part, is to convert into lists the comma-separated string values of countries and then to explode the 'country' column, then `groupby('country')` and get the `.sum()` of the attributes.

The problem that I have encountered is, that when I `groupby('country')`, there are countries which are repeated, for example United States is found with two different 'count' values as seen in the pics below.

(I need to underline that I have added to the original dataframe a column named 'count' which equals to the value 1 for every row and that `df_no_nan_country = df[df['country'].notna()]`)

Why is that happening and what can I do to fix it?

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df['count'] = 1
df_no_nan_country = df[df['country'].notna()]
df_split_countries = df_no_nan_country.assign(country=df['country'].str.split(',')).explode('country')
df_split_countries.groupby('country').sum()
df_split_countries_max = df_split_countries.groupby('country').sum()[df_split_countries.groupby('country').sum()['count']>100]
df_split_countries_max.head(30)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code/text and not pics.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try cleaning the column country before groupby

```
df_split_countries['country'] = df_split_countries['country'].str.strip()
df_split_countries['country'] = df_split_countries['country'].map(lambda x: .encode(x, errors="ignore").decode())
```

I think countries are repeated because they are not exactly the same string values, maybe one contain extra space...

Comment: You were right! By using the .strip() function the countries are not repeated anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a flag for coproductions and then explode?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
# drop null countries
df = df[df["country"].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)

# Flag for coproductions
df["countries_coproduction"] = df['country']\
    .str.split(',').apply(len).gt(1)

# Explode
df = df.assign(
    country=df['country'].str.split(','))\
   .explode('country')

# Clean coutries 
# removing lead/tail whitespaces
df["country"] = df["country"].str.lstrip().str.rstrip()
```

Then you can easily estract the top 10 countries in each case as

```py
grp[grp["countries_coproduction"]].nlargest(10, "n")\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

```bash
   countries_coproduction         country    n
0                    True   United States  872
1                    True  United Kingdom  387
2                    True          France  269
3                    True          Canada  264
4                    True         Germany  159
5                    True           China   96
6                    True           Spain   87
7                    True         Belgium   81
8                    True           India   74
9                    True       Australia   73
```

and

```py
grp[~grp["countries_coproduction"]].nlargest(10, "n")\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

```bash
   countries_coproduction         country     n
0                   False   United States  2818
1                   False           India   972
2                   False  United Kingdom   419
3                   False           Japan   245
4                   False     South Korea   199
5                   False          Canada   181
6                   False           Spain   145
7                   False          France   124
8                   False          Mexico   110
9                   False           Egypt   106
```